# What is the equivalent of hook_image_styles_alter()?

Tags: 8, media

I would like to allow uploading of SVG images to all the existing image fields with image effect. However, I wouldn't like the image styles to be applied to SVG images, as it is mostly designed for raster images.

I am thinking of detecting the format and avoid applying the styles to those formats.

Drupal 7 had `hook_image_styles_alter()`, but there is no equivalent in Drupal 8.